# Indentation error while converting csv to shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, csv

[image][image]
Why does this error occur?  what could have gone wrong with my code? Code:

```
import csv,shapefile

csvfile="C:\Python27\Conv.csv"
f=open(csvfile,'rb')
reader=csv.reader(f)
shp=shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
shp.point(2,3)
shp.point(3,1)
shp.point(4,3)
name,id=[],[]
shp.field('Name')
shp.field('Id')
for i,row in enumerate(i):
shp.record(row[i])
shp.save("conv.shp")
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question that you deleted: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237422  To avoid the automated asking bans I strongly recommend that you fix rather delete any questions that the community asks you to improve.

Comment: As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve error messages we ask that you show us them in full using text rather than a picture so that they can be searched and also read easily on all devices.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted text nicely.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Indentation error. Resolved. But I am unable to find the saved shapefile in C drive.

Answer (score 3):

Your last two lines need to be indented:

```
for i,row in enumerate(i):
    shp.record(row[i])
    shp.save("conv.shp")
```

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) convention is to indent using four spaces

Comment: Still the same error exists after pressing Enter. I get an error like 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: That is not the same error so you need to research, and if necessary ask, about it as a new question.